# OpenGL - Calling square function with different colour

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I have made a `drawSquare()` function that draws several 2D squares on my screen:

```
void drawSquare(GLfloat length, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat outline){
    // x1,y1 is the top left-hand corner coordinate
    // and so on...
    GLfloat x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4;

    x1 = x - length / 2;
    y1 = y + length / 2;
    x2 = x + length / 2;
    y2 = y + length / 2;
    x3 = x + length / 2;
    y3 = y - length / 2;
    x4 = x - length / 2;
    y4 = y - length / 2;

    // ACTUAL SQUARE OBJECT
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Colour: Cyan
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(x1, y1);     // vertex for BLUE SQUARES
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glVertex2f(x3, y3);
    glVertex2f(x4, y4);
    glEnd()
}
```

When I click a square, I need its colour to change. I already have a mouse function set up that displays the mouse location when I right click:

```
void processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN)){
        // gets mouse location
        printf("Clicked on pixel %d - %d", x, y);
        // prints to console
    }
}
```

and an `if statement` inside the above `if statement` like this:

```
    if (x > 0 && x < 95 && y > 302 && y < 395) { 
                // there's a square at this location!
                // change the square colour!
    }
```

When I place `exit(0);` inside this statement:

```
if (x > 0 && x < 95 && y > 302 && y < 395) { 
                exit(0);
}
```

My program exits fine, so the condition works, I just want to know **how I can somehow call my `drawSquare()` function again with a different colour**.

Initially when I call my `drawSquare()`, it's called in my display function like this:

```
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   /* clear window */
    // there are some other primatives here too
    drawSquare(100,150, 750,true);  // square drawn
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Here's how I fixed my issue. I made a global boolean variable boolean variable `areaClicked = false;` that checks if user has clicked, we set as false by default.

In my mouse function, I check if a square has been clicked, if so, set the boolean to true:

```
if (x >= 0 && x <= 95 && y >= 302 && y <= 380) { // area of box
            areaClicked = true;
}
```

Now in my display function, we check if the boolean has been triggered, if it has, then display my recoloured square, otherwise, do nothing:

```
if (areaClicked != false) {
        drawRecolour(100, 50, 350, true);   // 4th square drawn
}

else areaClicked = false;
```

Comment: Set a flag, trigger a redraw, and draw with a different color if the flag is set?

Comment: Could you maybe make a small example? I'm quite stuck...

Comment: Trim what you have down to a [mcve] and we'll work from there.  I'd recommend using GLUT or GLFW for context creation & input handling.

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully my problem is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler set a variable, then trigger a redraw.

```
if (x > 0 && x < 95 && y > 302 && y < 395) { 
            // there's a square at this location!
            // change the square colour!
            square_color = ...;
            glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

In your display function check for the variable and use that to determine the color:

```
// you should probably make the color a parameter of drawSquare
void drawSquare(GLfloat length, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat outline){

    // OpenGL doesn't do "objects". It **DRAWS** things. Like pen on paper

    glColor3f(square_color); // <---- uses variable
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
...
    glEnd()
}
```

Comment: Quick question, what's the square_color?

Comment: @BenTanos: some variable *you* have to define. You could name it anything you want to, place it in any scope that does the job. OpenGL is like a pen that draws on a piece of paper (that's provided by the OS). It draws points, lines or triangles, one at a time and the result is a nice picture. If you want a picture that looks different to what you already have drawn you have to redraw it – well technically you could just erase that part you want to change and *redraw* everything in the area erased, but usually it's easier to just redraw the whole thing.

Comment: Done! Although I didn't quite use your method, it still helped me a lot, therefore I will mark this answer as accepted and edit my question in a few minutes with how I fixed it. Thanks for the help!